# Does the recursive sequence $a_1 = 1, a_n = a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Does the recursive sequence $a_1 = 1, a_n = a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}$ converge?

Since the function $x+1/x$ is strictly monotonic increasing for all $x>1$, I don't think that the limit converges, but I'm not sure. Can anybody tell me whether the sequence is converging or not?

Comment: Before trying to find a formal proof, it helps to get some intuition. For that, I suggest sketching by hand the [web diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot) of your function.

Comment: Once you showed that it is not converging, you can find the speed by considering the differential equation $f'=1/f$

Comment: No, but at large values it does become linear!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. If it were convergent to some $\alpha$, this value would verify 
$$\alpha=\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha}.$$

Answer (score 15):

Note that $a_n^2 = \left(a_{n-1}+\dfrac{1}{a_{n-1}}\right)^2 = a_{n-1}^2 + 2 + \dfrac{1}{a_{n-1}^2} \ge a_{n-1}^2 + 2$.

Therefore, $a_n^2 \ge 2n-1$, and thus, $a_n \ge \sqrt{2n-1}$ for all $n \ge 1$. That's enough to show divergence.

Comment: How did you get that $a_n^2 \geq 2n-1$?

Comment: @Botond: $a_n^2 \ge a_1^2 + 2(n-1) = 2n-1$.

Answer (score 8):

Assume it converges, then it does so to a limit $L \ge 1$.

Then we have $L = L + \frac{1}{L}$ which is not possible.

Answer (score 6):

It is obvious that $a_n\le n$. Thus
$$a_{n+1}\ge a_n+\frac1n.$$
Since $H_n$ diverges, we can conclude that $a_n$ also diverges.

Comment: What does $H_n$ stand for?

Comment: @Vlad It is the harmonic series, defined as $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the equation $x= x+\frac1x$ does not have a solution. Therefore $a_n$ does not converges.  Also, since $a_1>0,$ by induction we easily have $a_n>0$ and 
then, $$a_{n+1} -a_n = \frac{1}{a_n}>0$$
**which means $(a_n)$ is a strictly increasing and non convergent sequence. So $a_n\to\infty$.**  That $a_n$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a_{n+1}=a_n$ + $\frac{1}{a_n}$ and  $a_n$

$\frac{1}{a_n}$ > $0$ we get that $a_{n+1}>a_n$

thus diverging