# How to tell if a recursively defined sequence diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_1:=a>0$ and $x_{n+1}:=x_n+1/x_n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Determine whether $(x_n)$ converges or diverges.

My answer:  $(x_n)$ is divergent.

Proof:  Assume that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$.  Then $\lim (x_{n+1})=\lim (x_n)$.  That is, $x=x+1/x$.  This equation has no solution.  Hence, $(x_n)$ is not convergent.  Therefore it is divergent.

My question.  Is the proof above a legitimate one?  Something just doesn't feel right to me.  Or should I just show that the sequence is unbounded.  Or am I altogether wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/887408/137524 has this same question

Comment: My apologies.  Often when I am searching for questions that involve subscripts, I don't have a lot of luck on Google or on this site.

Comment: That's fine. I had to search a little to find this one, but I knew it had recently shown up already.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is fine.

Note that *divergent* simply means that it is *not convergent*, not that it goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I can prove the stronger result: the sequence is unbounded and tends to $\infty$. 
It is given that $x_1=a>0$, so the first term is positive. By looking at the recurrence relation, it is clear that the entire sequence is positive ( can be proven easily by induction). Now, assume the sequence is bounded, so $x_n<L$ for all $n$ and some positive $L$. Hence, since $\frac{1}{n}$ is strictly decreasing for positive $n$, we have that $\frac{1}{x_n}>\frac{1}{L}$. Hence
$$ x_{n+1} = x_{n} + \frac{1}{x_n} > x_{n} + \frac{1}{L} $$ Hence, repeatedly applying this inequality, eventually the value of $x_n$ will surpass $L$. But we assumed that $L$ was an upper bound of the sequence, a contradiction. Hence, the sequence is unbounded. It is easy to show that the sequence is increasing. Hence the sequence is increasing and unbounded and therefore must tend to $\infty$.