# Proving that sequence ${a_n}$ is unbounded as $a_{n+1} = 1/{a_n} + {a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let ${a_1} > 0$ and ${a_n}$ be a sequence so that for any natural number

$a_{n+1} = 1/{a_n} + {a_n}$

**Prove that sequence ${a_n}$ is unbounded.**

How should I prove that? Can you give me any ideas ...

Comment: Since $a_{n+1}^2 \geq a_{n}^2+2$, $a_{n}$ grows faster than $\sqrt{2n}$.

Comment: Suppose it were bounded, and $B = \sup a_n$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I understand the ${a_{n+1}}^2 $ >=  ${a_n}^2 + 2$ part, but where did you get this $sqrt(2n)$ to compare it with $a_n$?

Comment: @Martiiin: by induction. If $a_{n+1}^2 \geq a_{n}^2+2$, then $a_{n+1}^2\geq (2n+C)$ hence $a_{n+1}\geq \sqrt{2n+C}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Show that sequence is positive and increasing. 
Therefore it has a positive limit. If this limit is finite, say $L$, then the recurrence relation $a_{n+1} = 1/{a_n} + {a_n}$ implies that
$$L=\frac{1}{L}+L.$$
What may we conclude?

Comment: See the answer of dontdeletemeplease [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887408/does-the-recursive-sequence-a-1-1-a-n-a-n-1-frac1a-n-1-converge).

Comment: @DietrichBurde which is the same as the answer of start wearing purple?

Comment: Then we may conclude that the sequence ${a_n} converges?

Comment: @Martiiin No. $a_n$ is increasing so it diverges (and it is unbounded) or it has a finite limit $L>0$, such that $L=1/L+L$. Therefore...

Comment: .. @RobertZ Therefore, since $ L = 1/L + L $ is not possible, the sequence $a_n$ doesn't have a finite limit L > 0, so it's increasing and it diverges and consequently it is unbounded.

Comment: Is this correct? :)

Comment: @Martiiin Yes, it is correct!